# C# interop Excel Issue

Tags: c#, excel, windows-10, office-interop, windows-7-x64

I have been stuck with this for almost a week, thank you so much in advance.

I created a simple component to export reports to Excel using Interop. I encountered that specifically for a 700K rows of information my Excel crashed for 32 bit installation, so after having a look deeply on this issue, the solution was to change Office to 64 bit edition, so I did.

My application is now running fine on 
Win10 64 bits / Office 64 bits / 16 Gb RAM / Core i7 Processor (700K rows of info)

But when I try to use this same application on 
Win7 64 bits / Office 64 bits / 32 Gb RAM / Core i7 Processor (700K rows of info) the application crashes with the following error:

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\\computerName\templates\template.xlsb'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Notice that the path is a shared folder in this same computer (Win7 one), privileges are given and the file exists in the folder.

Any idea on what's happening?